# Understanding boost spatial index queries documentation

Tags: c++, boost, geometry

I have trouble understanding queries in [Boost geometry spatial index documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/queries.html)

My understanding is that the red and green rectangles are not actually part of the data but symbolize internal nodes in the tree structure ? And that the black rectangles are actual data ?

## intersects(Box)

[image: intersects(Box)]

Assuming the Box in question is the biggest orange one, why are there 6 resulting small orange boxes, not just 2 (the two uppermost ones) ?

## overlaps(Box)

[image: overlaps(Box)]

Assuming the Box in question is the biggest orange one, why are there 3 black bloxes inside ? They seem to overlap with the biggest orange one, so I would assume they are orange (= part of the results).

## covered_by(Box)  and  within(Box)

What is the difference between these two functions ? The pictures seem exactly identical.

Comment: The image for overlaps is pretty different in the docs: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/img/index/rtree/overlaps.png

Answer (score 1):

1. The black rectangles are axis aligned bounding boxes of the actual data.
2. intersects(Box): the biggest orange box is equivalent to polygon, not linestring, so there are 6 results.
3. overlaps(Box): "The term spatially overlaps is used if two geometries intersect and their intersection results in a geometry of the same dimension but not equal to either of the given geometries", from [mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/overlaps/#:%7E:text=The%20term%20spatially%20overlaps%20is%20used%20if%20two,%28%29%20uses%20object%20shapes.%20Copyright%20%C2%A9%202020%20MariaDB.).
4. covered_by(Box) and within(Box): "covered_by" means one geometry is inside or on border the other geometry; "within" means one geometry is completely inside the other geometry. I think there's something wrong with the "covered_by" example.